# Advance Web Page Design

Tags: html, web

[image: Design something like this picture in web application]

I googled a lot for design something as the picture in HTML, but couldn't find anything hint. I wonder is it possible to design a web application in what picture show?

Comment: Yes it is. But until you have mad an attempt to do this your question is too broad in scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily implemented just using `HTML` and `CSS` but if you are pretty much comfortable with these two languages then I suggest you to learn `Bootstrap`.Using `Bootstrap` you can make even better than this.It has predefined classes for buttons,icons,header.tables,and lot more.Trust me,You'll love it.Hope this helps!!!!

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look very advanced to me.

- The laptop is an image
- Its container uses some shadows and gradients and
- The icons are also images.

Regarding the literal question: **Since it's already made, it's possible.**

All you need is: **HTML**, **CSS**, **JavaScript** and the desire to code.